# VRay interactive rendering

Tags: gpu, 3ds-max

I am building a 3DS Max workstation with i9 13900KS and dual RTX 4090 GPUs on a Maximus Z790 Hero mobo. I know the VRay GPU renderer will use both cards and increase render time. But is this the case with VRay interactive rendering? Would the dual GPUs have any impact on that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.